# convert struct handle from managed into unmanaged C++/CLI

Tags: c++, c++-cli, unmanaged

In C#, I defined a struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct MyObject
{
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
   public string var1;    

   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
   public string  var2;    
};
```

I have this struct in C++:

```
public value struct MyObject
{
    LPWSTR var1;    
    LPWSTR var2;    
};
```

And in the method of C++ which is a public class to be called from C#:

```
TestingObject(MyObject^ configObject)
{
   // convert configObject from managed to unmanaged.
}
```

The object is debugged correctly that I can see two strings var1 and var2. However, the problem now is that I need to marshal the object: `configObject` into an unmanaged object.

What I think of is to do something like this:

```
TestingObject(MyObject^ configObject)
{
   // convert configObject from managed to unmanaged.
   MyObject unmanagedObj = (MyObject)Marshal::PtrToStructure(configObject, MyObject);  
}
```

That is what I can think of but off course, I got this error:

> Error 2   error C2275: 'MyObject' : illegal use of this type as an
>   expression

Is that right to convert the managed object into unmanaged object? If so, how can I can that `Marshal::PtrToStructure` correctly? If no, how can I do it?

Comment: Your C# won't compile, unless you defined alias (or actual type) called `LPWSTR`.

Comment: it as my mistake. I just have updated it

Comment: Like @Botz alluded to in his answer, there are no unmanaged types here.  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Marshal::PtrToStructure` does the opposite of what you want, it converts an unmanaged pointer to a managed object. You want [`Marshal::StructureToPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.structuretoptr.aspx).

Also, you would need to define an unmanaged class, because MyObject is a Managed Type. Assuming you have done that, you could do it like this (just converted this from the C# sample):

```
IntPtr pnt = Marshal::AllocHGlobal(Marshal::SizeOf(configObject)); 
Marshal.StructureToPtr(configObject, pnt, false);
```

You then have a pointer to the data, which you can `memcpy` or whatever into your native struct.

**But** `MyObject` is and will stay a managed type. If you want a truly unmanaged type, you have to define one that matches the managed struct.

Just wondering, why are you using unmanaged LPWSTR in a managed struct?

Comment: I Just have updated my question which includes also the object in C# and you can see that I define the same one in C++. You are right that I copy the managed object configObject to pnt. But how can I create an unmanaged ConfigObject from that pnt? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those class definitions are both managed. Why are you not defining the class **only** in your C++ assembly and use that from C#? I mean you already referenced the library.  Then you would be using the same class.

Comment: I am not experienced with this topic to send a struct from C# to C++. So you mean I need to construct it in C++ first then use from C#. What should the struct definition in C++ be? could you please suggest me? Thanks in advance

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with it. Why does it need to be unmanaged? You could use the struct you already have in C++, but instead of LPWSTR, use String^. That way, you could use it from both C# and C++.

Comment: well. I just have tried to update the struct both in C# and C++ as advised by Paul below. var1 will be String^. In order to print it, I have to it like this: printf((const char*)(Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(myObject->var1)).ToPointer()); but I got an exception at that line

Comment: Why don't you try `Console::WriteLine(myObject->var1)` ?

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean:

```
struct MyUnmanagedStruct {
    LPWSTR var1, var2;
};
```

Then you can use `Marshal.StructureToPtr`as suggested by Botz3000. Otherwise C#'s

```
public struct MyObject {
   public String var1;
   public String var2;
}
```

and C++/CLI's

```
public struct value MyObject {
   public String^ var1;
   public String^ var2;
}
```

are completely equivalent, assuming your're you're using the same `System.String` on both sides.

Comment: thanks. Because I asked another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9651585/how-to-set-an-object-into-c-from-c-sharp and they suggested to use LPWSTR. For your other solution, I need to convert String^ to string in C++, right?

Comment: Hm, no or yes... since I am not sure what you are up to right now. In the other thread you asked how to make a .NET object available to native c++. Yes, the answer you got there is a possible way, though not the most elegant, nor the safest. From what you've posted here, it appears as you were trying to do something strange: store unmanged strings in a managed value type `public value struct MyObject`...